# How many multiplications at a minimum must be performed in order to calculate this polynomial

Tags: polynomials

How many multiplications at a minium must be performed in order to calculate the polynomial expression :  $$x^{4} - 2x^3 + 5x^2 + x - 6 $$

Does this question mean I have to shorten the expression above to something like (the expression below is just an assumed one) :

$$x -2 = 6 - 5x$$

And now count how many multiplication must be performed?

Comment: Try $-6+x(1+5x-2x^2+x^3)$ and compare the number of multiplications. Can you do better again?

Comment: Look (Wikipedia or elsewhere)  for Horner's Method.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it this way, you only need to do three multiplications.
$$
x^4 - 2x^3 + 5x^2 + x - 6 = x(x^3 - 2x^2 + 5x + 1) - 6 = x(x(x^2 - 2x + 5)+1)-6=x(x(x(x-2)+5)+1)-6
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a polynomial of the fourth degree and it has four complex roots. It can be written as  $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)$ where $x_1 , x_2 ,x_3,x_4$-roots of the polynomial . Here you have 3 multiplication and you can't get less becouuse for getting $x^4$ you need 3 multiplication

Comment: How many multiplications require $(x-1)^4=((x-1)^2)^2$?

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla , It need 2 multipcitions . But polinomail $x^4−2x^3+5x^2+x−6$ cannot be represeneted as $(x+a)^4$ so we can't get it using 2 multiplications.

Comment: True. My point is that your *argument* is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowed to use a temporary variable, 
the number of multiplications can be reduced to 2, for example:
$$y=x\cdot x;\quad (y-x-x+5)\cdot y+x-6.$$